# Could not parse mapping document from resource hbm/xml/Items.hbm.xml and Duplicate class/entity mapping bean.ItemTable

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

This is my first Hibernate application. Been stuck here for 2 days. Need Help. Package Over view: small letters: Package capital letters: class

src->dao->OPERATIONS.JAVA src->hbm.xml->items.hbm.xml

src->Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
public class Operations {

    public static void main(String [] args){

    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf=null;
        sf=cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session sess=sf.openSession();
    if(sess==null)
            System.out.println("Session Object :  NULL:  "+sess);
        Transaction tx=sess.beginTransaction();
        ItemTable ob=new ItemTable();
        ob.setItemCode(1);
        ob.setItemName("ATTA");
        sess.save(ob);
        sess.flush();//generates SQL queries
        tx.commit();
        sess.close();
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:Oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name ="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin1234</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property  name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <!-- To display the sql generated in console -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <!-- For JDBC transactions -->

        <mapping resource="hbm/xml/Items.hbm.xml"/> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Items.hfm.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

 <hibernate-mapping  auto-import ="true">
    <class name="bean.ItemTable" table ="items">
    <!-- Every class must have an Id(Primary Key) or Composite_Id -->
        <id name ="itemCode" column="ITEMCODE" type="integer">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="itemName" column="ITEMNAME" type="string"/>     
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```